# Grid rows height & SpanFromAbove issue

Tags: bugs, grid-layouts

**Bug introduced in 9 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

---

I would like to understand why the following code produces such a different result (Mathematica 9, Win7). Is this a bug? Is there a way to avoid this line height problem?

```
Grid[
 {{"a", "b", "c", "d"},
  {"L1\nL2\nL3", "e", SpanFromLeft, "f"},
  {SpanFromAbove, "g", SpanFromLeft, "h"},
  {SpanFromAbove, "i", SpanFromLeft, "j"},
  {SpanFromAbove, "k", SpanFromLeft, "l"}}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
Grid[
 {{"a", "b", "c", "d"},
  {"L1\nL2\nL3", "e", "m", "f"},
  {SpanFromAbove, "g", SpanFromLeft, "h"},
  {SpanFromAbove, "i", SpanFromLeft, "j"},
  {SpanFromAbove, "k", SpanFromLeft, "l"}}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**:

Maybe I oversimplified my need making the question difficult to understand. Here is a more practical example of the problem:

```
Grid[
 {{"", SpanFromLeft, "simple\nmodel", "improved\nmodel"},
  {"Test\nSim\nParams", "param1 =", 1, SpanFromLeft},
  {SpanFromAbove, "param2 =", 2, 3},
  {SpanFromAbove, "param3 =", 4, 5},
  {SpanFromAbove, "param4 =", 6, 7}}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason you didn't put "m" in the first one and what is the expected result?

Comment: The first one more closely matches the real (much bigger) table that I am working on.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino It's not clear what you need: are you saying you have data like the first table but want it to look like the second table?

Comment: I need the same row height for all rows in the first table. For some reason, when I merge two columns this becomes difficult.

Comment: This is a very good question, and I tried for several hours to find an answer. `SpanFromLeft` in the second row should not trigger `SpanFromAbove`, there is no apologize for such nasty behaviour. In my opinion it's a bug.

Comment: I just tried this on the Wolfram Cloud and this bug is not present in there (but there seems to be a different issue with the dividers).

Comment: I have just confirmed that this bug is still present in Mathematica 10.1

Comment: This is still broken in 10.3.1

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that `SpanFromLeft` match the dimensions of the first cell in the row (which is "Test\nSim\nParams"). the first cell is bigger than the others in the same levels.

you may try some thing like this:

```
Grid[{
  {"", SpanFromLeft, "simple\nmodel", "improved\nmodel"},
  {"Test   ", "param1 =", 1, SpanFromLeft},
  {"Sim\nParams", "param2 =", 2, 3},
  {SpanFromAbove, "param3 =", 4, 5},
  {SpanFromAbove, "param4 =", 6, 7}
  },
 Frame -> {All, 
   1 -> True, {{{3, 4}, {2, 4}} -> True, {{4, 4}, {2, 4}} -> True}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is the closest to the updated question. Why don't you show the output ???

Comment: @eld, I was so busy. thanks.

Comment: (+1) Your assumption that `SpanFromLeft` match the dimensions of the first cell in the row contradicts the following: `Grid[{{"","",SpanFromLeft,"simple\nmodel","improved\nmodel"},{"","Test\nSim\nParams","param1 =",1,SpanFromLeft},{"",SpanFromAbove,"param2 =",2,3},{"",SpanFromAbove,"param3 =",4,5},{"",SpanFromAbove,"param4 =",6,7}},Dividers->All]`. Now the first cell in the row contains only `""` but the heigh of the row is still the same.

Comment: Maybe SpanFromLeft matches the dimensions of the largest cell in the row.